# How to calculate the file read time of a job?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, parquet

I was running a spark sql job in spark-shell, the job create a table from parquet file.

On the web UI of the driver node, there are many metrics for a task:

Duration / Scheduler Delay / Task Deserialization Time / GC Time / Result Serialization Time / Getting Result Time / Write Time

I want to know how much time was really spent on reading the parquet block from disk(do not include the time of deserialization, reconstruction of tuple, shuffle write and so on).

How should I calculate that? Is

read time=Duration - Scheduler Delay - Task Deserialization Time - GC Time - Result Serialization Time - Getting Result Time - Write Time ?

Thanks,

Comment: hi @Hank i have same issue.....have you find the solution.....if yes than please update your answer...thanks